# How to customize stanfordNLP tokenizer to ignore asterisk character?

Tags: tokenize, stanford-nlp

I'm using stanfordCoreNLP library's tokenizer as a part of my project.For the following string
 `abc def *ghi`
It is giving the following tokens`abc,def,*ghi`
But,I want asterisk to be included as in `abc,def,*ghi`.How to customize PBTTokenizer to acheive this?

Comment: Could you clarify what output you are getting and what output you would like to achieve?

Comment: 'abc def *ghi' -> present output: 'abc',def','*','ghi' I want * to be with 'ghi' i.e.'abc','def','*ghi'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer for this question:

[How to set delimiters for PTB tokenizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688640/how-to-set-delimiters-for-ptb-tokenizer/32695789#32695789)

You can set the tokenizer to tokenize on white space only:

```
(command-line) -tokenize.whitespace
(in Java code) props.setProperty("tokenize.whitespace", "true");
```