# How to set delimiters for PTB tokenizer?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, stanford-nlp, stringtokenizer

I'm using StanfordCore NLP Library for my project.It uses PTB Tokenizer for tokenization.For a statement that goes like this-
`go to room no. #2145` or

```
go to room no. *2145
```

tokenizer is splitting #2145 into two tokens: #,2145. Is there any way possible to set tokenizer so that it does't identify #,* like a delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to use this option:

```
(command-line) -tokenize.whitespace
(in Java code) props.setProperty("tokenize.whitespace", "true");
```

This will cause the tokenizer to just tokenize on white space.  Do you need it to do anything other than tokenize on white space?

Comment: I tried this before.This works only when we have one sentence that is to be tokenized. If the input text is something like -"go to room *2005.pick up a pen." It identifies "*2005pick" as a single token